# How to insert blank page every seven pages

Tags: pdftk

I need to insert a blank page every 7 pages of a document consists of about 737 pages.
How can I do this with pdftk?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please tell us what you have researched and how you have attempted to resolve this. More information available the better. Please take a couple of minutes and read:http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer,https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Under `Windows`, you could use a `CMD` or `BAT` script similar to the following:

```
set INP=VLSI Architectures for Computations in Galois Fields.pdf
set BLANK=blankSheet.pdf

pdftk A="%INP%" B="%BLANK%" cat A01-07 B A08-14 B A15-21 B A22-28 B A29-35 B output out1.pdf
pdftk A="%INP%" B="%BLANK%" cat A36-42 B A43-49 B A50-56 B A57-63 B A64-70 B output out2.pdf
pdftk A="%INP%" B="%BLANK%" cat A71-77 B A78-84 B A85-91 B A92-98 B A99-106 B output out3.pdf
pdftk A=out1.pdf B=out2.pdf C=out3.pdf cat A B C output out.pdf
```

Make sure that `pdftk.exe` is found along your search `PATH`.
For `Unix` shell scripts, the syntax should be fairly similar.